# SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, runtime-error

I am running a Python code where I have to get some data from `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ssd.jpl.nasa.gov', port=443)`. But each time I try to run the code I get the following error. I am on MAC OS 12.1

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ssd.jpl.nasa.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/horizons.api?format=text&EPHEM_TYPE=OBSERVER&QUANTITIES_[...]_ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I really don't know how to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error comes up when using OpenSSL 3 to connect to a server which does not support it. The solution is to downgrade the cryptography package in python:

run `pip install cryptography==36.0.2` in the used enviroment.

source: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5491

EDIT: Refer to Harry Mallon and ahmkara's answer for a fix without downgrading cryptography

Comment: Didn't worked for me and `api.searchads.apple.com`

Comment: I had same problem with python requests 2.28.1 via cryptography 37.0.2. I downgraded the cryptography to 36.0.2 and problem fixed. tnx a lot :X

Comment: Tried with python3.8, 3.9, 3.10 on ubuntu 22.04 - no luck

Comment: This isn’t quite accurate - it’s not OpenSSL 3 but a server or tampering proxy which supports TLS 1.2 but not either the [RFC 5746](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5746) secure renegotiation extension or TLS 1.3 - but it’s dangerous advice since using old versions of cryptography means you aren’t patching security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @MartinHansen having similar issues on ubuntu 22.04. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 130):

**WARNING: When enabling Legacy Unsafe Renegotiation, SSL connections will be vulnerable to the Man-in-the-Middle prefix attack as described in [CVE-2009-3555](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CAN-2009-3555).**

With the help of https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1963834
and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls28/+bug/1856428

Beware that editing your system's openssl.conf is not recommended, because you might lose your changes once openssl is updated.

Create a custom `openssl.cnf` file in any directory with these contents:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

Before running your program, make sure your `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable is set to your custom `openssl.cnf` full path when running the scraper like so:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/custom/openssl.cnf python your_scraper.py
```

or like so:

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/custom/openssl.cnf
python your_scraper.py
```

or, if you are using pipenv or systemd or docker, place this into your `.env` file

```
OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/custom/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, although I don't fully don't understand what I'm doing. (just trying to get TD ameritrade stocks. Was working before upgrading to 22.04) The file to edit is ```Modify the existing openssl config file, path: /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf```

Comment: @Chad It is not recommended to change system defaults because they might be overridden by package changes. Happens to everyone. There is a cleaner way, I'm editing the answer to publish a working example.

Comment: Worked for me ... I was facing problems using Ubuntu 22.04 (openssl 3.0.2) which is default python 3.10.6. I can not download a corpus using nltk.download() as source seems to use legacy functions ... I am getting this [nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED]

Answer (score 51):

Complete code snippets for [Harry Mallon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394228/harry-mallon)'s answer:

Define a method for reuse:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import ssl


class CustomHttpAdapter (requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    # "Transport adapter" that allows us to use custom ssl_context.

    def __init__(self, ssl_context=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_context = ssl_context
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_context=self.ssl_context)


def get_legacy_session():
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
    ctx.options |= 0x4  # OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT
    session = requests.session()
    session.mount('https://', CustomHttpAdapter(ctx))
    return session
```

Then use it in place of the requests call:

```
get_legacy_session().get("some-url")
```

Comment: Nice! I now simply used `with (get_legacy_session() as s, s.get("some-url") as response)` and it works. Very useful for deployment in google cloud (as I could not downgrade SSL here)

Comment: does not work
'''
r = get_legacy_session().post(url, params=params, data=payload)
'''

Answer (score 34):

I hit the same error on Linux (it happens when the server doesn't support "RFC 5746 secure renegotiation" and the client is using OpenSSL 3, which enforces that standard by default).

Here is a solution (you may have to adjust it slightly).

1. Import `ssl` and `urllib3` in your Python code
2. Create a custom HttpAdapter which uses a custom `ssl` `Context`

```py
class CustomHttpAdapter (requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    '''Transport adapter" that allows us to use custom ssl_context.'''

    def __init__(self, ssl_context=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_context = ssl_context
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_context=self.ssl_context)
```

3. Set up an `ssl` context which enables `OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT`, and use it with your custom adapter.

`ssl.OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT` is not available in Python yet (https://bugs.python.org/issue44888). However it turns out that in OpenSSL its value is 0x4 in the bitfield. So we can do the following.

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
ctx.options |= 0x4
session.mount('https://', CustomHttpAdapter(ctx))
```

Comment: Hey Harry! I tried to use your code but I get unresolved references for requests. and session. as they are not defined

Comment: `session` is an instance of `requests.Session()`. My code snippets are incomplete as they were taken from a larger project. You will have to adjust them to fit your code.

Comment: This leads to: ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.

simply add, then it should be running
>>> ctx.check_hostname = False
>>> ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

Comment: This also worked for me, probably the best future proof alternative to downgrading

Comment: Can confirm this solution works! No need to downgrade as per accepted answer.

Comment: This works, the question is: Am I vulnerable to the Man-in-the-Middle prefix attack as described in CVE-2009-3555 if I use this solution?

Comment: Setting this setting sets OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT. This is described in the OpenSSL man pages under 'SECURE RENEGOTIATION' https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_options.html

Comment: this was the only workaround that worked for me

Comment: I would add that the best fix long-term is to upgrade your servers to support TLS 1.3. I’ve had good luck getting some third-parties to upgrade their CDN’s TLS config to work around this problem as exposed by defective Palo Alto appliances which don’t support RFC 5746.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use urlopen, this snippet worked for me.

```
import ssl
import urllib.request

url = 'http://....'

# Set up SSL context to allow legacy TLS versions
ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
ctx.options |= 0x4  # OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT

# Use urllib to open the URL and read the content
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't really answer the issue, but a coworker switched from Node 18 to 16 and stopped getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the same problem in ruby you can do below:

```
# Set OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT option
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options] |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT

# Make a request
uri = URI('https://example.com')
res = Net::HTTP.post(uri, {}.to_json)

# Unset OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT option
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options] &= ~OpenSSL::SSL::OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT
```

Comment: Finally! Days wasted to find this work around. This is the perfect solution when you are stuck with an outdated server and cannot upgrade your libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `conda`, usually conda installs a new openssl executable with each environment. One easy fix is to downgrade your openssl to 1.0 by running the following with your environment.

```bash
conda install -n conda-env-name openssl=1
```

Or find where the openssl config is for your specific conda environment and follow Jack Lee's answer.

You'll have to closely monitor the SSL versions from this website to ensure you specify the correct channel. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openssl/labels

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few answers on this thread.  None of them quite met my needs, so I figured I'd contribute my own solution as well.  Hopefully others find it valuable.

*My Setup*

I am running Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.2.  I am using `aiohttp` to make HTTP requests asynchronously.

I am making an HTTP request to a piece of hardware on my internal LAN, and I cannot update this hardware to simply stop using the insecure SSL renegotiation.

*My Approach*

I created a custom SSL context, and then passed in the SSL OP flag 'SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION'.  I got this flag from here: [List of SSL OP Flags](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/List_of_SSL_OP_Flags)

```
custom_ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
custom_ssl_context.options |= 0x00040000 # OP flag SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION

connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=custom_ssl_context)

async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()
```

If you also need to disable SSL verification (in the case of development testing for example), you can add the following two lines to your custom_ssl_context:

```
custom_ssl_context.check_hostname = False
custom_ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I downgraded python to `v3.10.8.`

(If you are facing the issue in docker container, read below)

In my docker image, I was using alpine-10 which was using v3.10.9. Since I couldn't get alpine with v3.10.8, I used 3.10.8-slim-bullseye.

Comment: The Python version is a red herring: the problem is caused by the version of OpenSSL shipped in that container. Alpine upgraded earlier than Debian but the same behavior will manifest on both as soon as you use any version of Python with OpenSSL 3 or later.

Comment: Upgrading to 3.10.9-slim from 3.10  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Now I resolve issue it   - [SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled]
or (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1007)')))
reference link below : but it's not used just try to understand the problem

([SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled))
use below code :

```
import urllib.request
import ssl

# Create a secure SSL context
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)  # Use the appropriate protocol

url = "https://example.com"  # Replace with your URL
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ssl_context)

# Read and process the response
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score -3):

For me, I switch the url from https into  http.
Please be aware that HTTP does not provide the same level of security as HTTPS

Comment: There are _very_ few valid reasons for using plain HTTP in 2023