# how to avoid SSL certificate error while scraping a webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to scrape petrol prices from below page using `requests`, but am getting below error.

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.goodreturns.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /petrol-price-in-karnataka-s17.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1131)')))`

below is the code which I have tried.

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.goodreturns.in/petrol-price-in-karnataka-s17.html',verify=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled)

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass headers along with your request to make it authentic. Pass headers parameters as following:

```
import requests
headers = {'Host': 'www.goodreturns.in',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.goodreturns.in/petrol-price-in-karnataka-s17.html', headers = headers)
```