# SOAP request with ZEEP module in python raising requests.exceptions.SSLError?

Tags: python, zeep

I am trying to send a SOAP request using the zeep module in python.

The detail error is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='PLACEHOLDER_URL.COM', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /PLACEHOLDER.asmx?WSDL (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I found solutions in the requests module to set `verify=False` if you don't want to validate the certificate. But no similar solution for for my use case.

zeep version: '4.2.0';
python version: '3.10.6'

Comment: Your remote host has disable renegotiation without signalling it correctly. To solve this, you will need a custom SSL context for the requests lib being used by zeep. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled/71646353#71646353) is quite helpful.