# SSL Error in Python Requests run from Github's Actions

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, github-actions

I am trying to periodically download data in Python from parliamentary website https://www.psp.cz/ using Github's Actions.
(For example this data file: https://www.psp.cz/eknih/cdrom/opendata/poslanci.zip )

I am able to download it OK at my local computer, but it does not work from Github Actions returning error: `SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')`

My basic code in `downloader.py`:

```py
import requests
url = "https://www.psp.cz/eknih/cdrom/opendata/poslanci.zip"
r = requests.get(url)
```

My code in `YML` file for Github Actions:

```yaml
# ... set when to run the Actions here

jobs:
  scheduled:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check out repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'
- uses: actions/cache@v3
      name: Configure pip caching
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pip
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Download data
      run: python downloader.py

    # ... do something with the data here

    - name: Commit and push if it changed
      run: |-
        git config user.name "Automated"
        git config user.email "actions@users.noreply.github.com"
        git add -A
        timestamp=$(date +%FT%T%Z)
        git commit -m "Latest data: ${timestamp}" || exit 0
        git push
```

And `requirements.txt` is simply:

```
requests
```

I've tried several variants, but with no success:

```py
r = requests.get(url)
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
r = requests.get(url, verify=True)
# files obtained from Firefox's data/info about `psp.cz` website:
r = requests.get(url, verify='psp-cz.pem')
r = requests.get(url, verify='psp-cz-chain.pem')
# all 5 ends with: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.psp.cz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /eknih/cdrom/opendata/poslanci.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Any idea how to set it up correctly? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled

Comment: @SarahMesser I tried also to use the solution from there adding `cryptography==36.0.2` into `requests.txt`, but I'm getting still the same error

Comment: @MichalSkop: Alternatively, you can use `wget` command e.g. `wget https://www.psp.cz/eknih/cdrom/opendata/poslanci.zip`.