# SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, ansible, ansible-awx

I'm using AWX (deployed by k8s) to manage my infrastructure, and all the playbooks are stored in Gitlab, in the past I can reach Gitlab without any issues but recently my company changes the visibility policies from private to internal, and somehow now I can't sync the project from gitlab to AWX and I'm getting the error below:

**error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled**

I followed this guide [SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled) to modify the `openssl.cnf` but I'm getting the same error. How can i set the `UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation` option for my kubernetes deployment??? thank you!

[SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Create a configmap with your `openssl.cnf`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: openssl-cnf
data:
  # This openssl conf is used to allow Openssl v >= 3.0.4 to connect
  # to servers that have TLS v1.2 with secure renegotiation disabled
  openssl.cnf: |
    ...
    [openssl_init]
    ssl_conf = ssl_sect

    [ssl_sect]
    system_default = system_default_sect

    [system_default_sect]
    Options = UnsafeLegacyServerConnect
    ...
```

Then mount that CM to your deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: 'your-container'
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
          name: openssl-cnf
          subPath: openssl.cnf
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: openssl-cnf
        name: openssl-cnf
```