# Mocking an SSLError in Python

Tags: python, ssl, testing

I've been dealing with the `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled` issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled). As part of the fix, I'm attempting to write in exception-handling for the exception:

```
try:
    return req()
except (ssl.SSLError, RSSLError) as ssl_err:
    print(ssl_err)
    if "UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED" in str(ssl_err):
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
        ctx.options |= 0x4
        self._sess.mount("https://", CustomHttpAdapter(ctx))
        return req()
    raise
```

The issue I'm having is testing it. I've tried doing this:

```
err = SSLError()
err.reason = "UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED"
```

but this prints as `()`. How do I create a mock `SSLError` that I can use to test this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the string as your argument to the constructor:

```
>>> from ssl import SSLError
>>> error = SSLError("UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED")
>>> print(error)
('UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED',)
```

Comment: I'm feeling a mixture of gratitude at this quick answer and disgust with myself for not having realized this was possible. At any rate, thanks!