# I have problem on GIT inside VS2022 only. Pull by cmd has no issue

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio

My OS is Windows, In the specific wifi, I have to input command

```
Git config –global http.sslVerify false
```

to GIT for pull/push the repo.

If I use GIT by command, it doesn't have any issue after that command.

However when I use the GIT in Visual Studio 2022, I get an error:

> OpenSSL/3.1.1: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Does anyone know how to set that Git config above in VS2022 or another solution?

Comment: TLS connections expect the server to send the renegotiation_info extension. Configure the git server to support secure renegotiation as per TLS Renegotiation Indication Extension (RFC 5746).

Comment: You may follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245418/6752050

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/72245418/6752050 is when the whole has problem but my case only problem at VS2022. I am not sure this is the same case however I cannot find the way to config the openssl under vs2022

Comment: Oh I see, stackoverflow.com/a/72245418/6752050 can fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a solution for GIT in Windows, I was able to fix the issue by doing the following:

1. Created a custom openssl.conf file with the content described in the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245418/6752050
2. Added environment variable by opening a command prompt and entering: set "OPENSSL_CONF=c:\GIT\openssl.cnf"

Once this was done I was able to clone successfully.