# Enable unsafe legacy renegotiation in exchangelib

Tags: python, ssl, exchangelib

I have issues enabling unsafe legacy renegotiations in exchangelib. I'm behind a corpo network and that's the underlying problem as far as I know. The same script when I'm connected to a personal network works fine but there's nothing I can do about the networking of my company. I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled) and I'm trying to implement their solution but I still get the error:

`exchangelib.errors.TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='outlook.office365.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /EWS/Exchange.asmx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1006)')))`

This is the simplest script I can manage to recreate the error:

```py
import ssl
from exchangelib import Account, BaseProtocol, Configuration, Credentials, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
import requests
import urllib3

class CustomHttpAdapter (requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    # "Transport adapter" that allows us to use custom ssl_context.

    def __init__(self, ssl_context=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_context = ssl_context
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_context=self.ssl_context)

def get_legacy_session():
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
    ctx.options |= ssl.Options.OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION
    session = requests.session()
    session.mount('https://', CustomHttpAdapter(ctx))
    return session

BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
requests.Session = get_legacy_session

credentials = Credentials(username="my_username@outlook.it", password="my_password")
config = Configuration(server="outlook.office365.com", credentials=credentials)

account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address=credentials.username,
    config=config,
    autodiscover=False
)
```

EDIT: python 3.12 - exchangelib 5.1.0

Comment: It looks like you asked the same thing in the exchangelib issue tracker: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/1259 Maybe you want to share the solution here?

Comment: Also, this isn't really about exchangelib. I think you would get the same with `import requests; requests.get("https://outlook.office365.com")`

Comment: No. this is a different error. My solution was to containerize my application in a different environment with a different network. What I am asking is if it's possibile to allow said regulations when creating the Account object hence I do think it's about exchangelib. With requests, I can solve similar issues just fine by following the linked question solution.

Comment: The example code above doesn't actually use `CustomHttpAdapter` - you're still setting `NoVerifyHTTPAdapter` as `BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS `. Maybe that's the issue? You probably also meant `requests.Session = get_legacy_session()` instead of `requests.Session = get_legacy_session`

Comment: `CustomHttpAdapter` gets mounted inside `get_legacy_session`. Adding parenthesis didn't change anything, same error. Without `NoVerifyHTTPAdapter` I get an error about using a self-signed-certificate. I'll keep looking for an alternative way to overcome this issue, I'm sure not everone behind an annoying corpo network can solve this issue in the same way I did. Thank you for your time all the same!